# how to use maximum network flow to solve this?

Tags: algorithm, network-flow

suppose we are given a network which Node A sends 2 packet to Node B and for security reasons we want these two packets get different paths to reach Node B.How can I use Maximum Network Flow to determine is it possible in a given Network?

I guess I should consider all capacities one and if two packets have to pass through common edge the maximum Network Flow will be 1 and the given Network won't be able to do this task else it is capable.But I'm not sure is it true to consider a Capacity for all edges?

Comment: You might want node capacities of 1.

Comment: do you mean instead of capacity for edge i use capacity for nodes?  how is it a Maximum Network Flow problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27463037/2144669

Comment: thanks complete answer